# routing using connect - similar to express

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I am trying to change the below code using connect module and connect-route. Currently it is written in express.

```
//app.js
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use("/shop/rackOne", rackOne);
app.listen(1000);

//rackOne.js
var express = require('express');
var shoes = require('./shoes.js');
var router = express.Router();
router.all('/stock', shoes);

//shoes.js
function shoes(req, res, next) {
var body = req.body;
}
module.exports = shoes;
```

Issues which I am facing

> 1. Not able to read body data. In connect, no req.body is available.
> 2. No .all router is available.

Code change using connect

```
var connectRoute = require('connect-route'),
    connect = require('connect'),
    app = connect();

app.use(connectRoute(function (router) {
    router.get('/shop/rackOne', rackOne);
    });
```

I am not sure. Is this the correct way to do it. Any help on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure to understand what you want here, but I'll try to answer.

From the [npm page of connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect), all I can offer you to try is this :

```
var connectRoute = require('connect-route');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();

app.use(function yourFunctionFromMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    // use req, res as you wish
    next();
});
```

I used connect once, and I used this code, which worked properly for what I needed back there, not sure what you are trying to do here though.